# What rule of inference is used in the following example? "All cows are black", "the cow is in the cage" therefore "the cow in the cage is black"

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

I suppose this example is a type of syllogism but I'm not sure how to write it formally as a proof. Could you help me please?

Comment: See [Universal Instantiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_instantiation). I'm sure there are other terms for this also, by the way.

Comment: In the second statement, "cow" seems to denote an individual, like a name; i.e., one could write something like "The cow Socrates is in the cage" to emphasize this more. Then I suppose "[the] cow in the cage" is really a reference to said cow, i.e., this really should be interpreted as "Socrates (the cow) is black". I suppose in this form, you are happier with the problem

Comment: A formal proof is a proof in a proof system which will specify a language and a bunch of rules and axioms. Different proof systems have different rules and axioms. If you want to write a *formal* proof, you need to specify a proof system such as natural deduction (and, say, specifically **NJ** as "natural deduction" itself covers a wide class of proof systems). It is quite possible that you are more interested in an ***in**formal* proof. Most proofs in mathematics are informal.